# how to initialize DB triggers in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot, I put some DDLs inside `schemal.sql` and it works well, but it seems it can't parse trigger functions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updated_column() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.updated = now();
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER updated_time BEFORE UPDATE ON entries FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE  updated_column();
```

this throws exceptions while Spring starts up.
How should I initialize triggers?

Comment: what are the exceptions, have the tables been created before the trigger script runs ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky in this case, it gives ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception, however, this executes fine in postgres console.

Comment: I would suggest using flyway or liquibase for this. The support schemas is quite limited I would say, it parses the file and tries to commit per line (line is determined by detecting the ending ;). So you probably want/might want to use a stronger mechanism.